# Position laser-controls entity after camera rotation

Tags: aframe, webvr

I have the following code for the laser controls which are perfectly positioned when the camera looks straight ahead after entering VR mode.

```
<a-entity position="0.25 1.25 -0.2" class="laser-controls">
  <a-entity laser-controls="hand: right" line="color: red"></a-entity></a-entity>
```

The issue is: when I rotate my head (camera), I would like to let the controls follow my head rotation smoothly (I have some code which looks if the rotation is greater than 110 degrees). I don't want the controllers be part of the camera since they should keep their own independent rotation. What I like is the behaviour of the controller model in Oculus Home (Gear VR).

How can I achieve this is my custom component, let's say in my tick function, which is called every two seconds (that code works already).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about using `getAttribute()` to check the rotation of the camera component and the laser control's entity? Then you could check if the difference exceeds 110 degrees or not:

```
let angle = laser.getAttribute('rotation');
if (camera.getAttribute('rotation').y - laser.getAttribute('rotation').y>110){
   angle.y++;
   laser.setAttribute('rotation',angle);
} else if(camera.getAttribute('rotation').y - laser.getAttribute('rotation').y<-110){
   angle.y--;
   laser.setAttribute('rotation',angle);
}
```

**UPDATE**
If You want to position Your controller near Your head You can:

1.Instead of `angle.y++/--` change it to Your camera's rotation. You can also change its x/y position close to the camera ( like camera.position.x + 0.5 )

2.But the above is instant, if You want to make it smooth, You could use the animation component, when the delta degree is >110 deg, set the animation attributes to move to the camera component location/rotation, emit a beginning event, disable the rotation check, listen for the animation end event, and enable the check. a bit like this:

```
init: function(){
  this.check = true;
  let check = this.check;
  animationel.addEventListener('animationend',function(){
      check = true;
  });
},tick(){
    if(this.check){
        if(rotationCheck()){
           this.check = false;
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. But this code changes just the rotation of the controller. If the controller sits on the right hand side just below the camera in the initial rotation, and if I turn my head > 110 degrees, it just rotates the controller model, but it does not move next to my new head rotation (where it sat at the initial pose). If I turn my head then the controller is on the left side of the camera because it just stayed where it was.

Comment: I added a codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/awQRdm The controller does not stay besides the camera, tested in Gear VR with controller. I think this controller behaviour could become a component as this functionality is needed by many people.